# When a quest is completed in my game, money gets re-set rather than added

Tags: unity, 3d

I have two quests in the game I am trying to create and each of the quests gives 50 coins if the quest is completed successfully and when I finish the first quest, I am given 50 coins and all is cool!

There's a problem when I complete the second quest: it has to give me additional 50 and overall I have to have 100 coins. However when I complete the second quest, it, kind of, regives me 50 coins and overall I have 50 coins but it has to be 100.

Here is the code I am using:

```
The fragment of quest 2 and 1 script since they are identical
------------------------------

 void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
    {

        if (col.tag == "Player" & Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            Money.MoneyAmount = +50;//here I am trying to reference Money class
            exclamation.SetActive(false);

            if (TextBoxOnCheck == 0)
            {
                BaseQuest.QuestNumber = 0;
                TextBoxOnCheck = 1; //Sets the variable to turn the box off
                MessageBox.SetActive(true); //Re-enables the box

                TextBox.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Local rezident: Thank you a lot"; //changes the message                                
                QuestText.SetActive(false); // input the quest name

The money class handles adding coins to UI text
-----------------------------------------------


public class Money : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int MoneyAmount;
    public int InternalMoney;
    public GameObject MoneyDisplay;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        InternalMoney = MoneyAmount;
        MoneyDisplay.GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + InternalMoney;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

At this line it looks like you're setting the money amount to exactly positive 50, regardless of what it was before:

```
Money.MoneyAmount = +50;//here I am trying to reference Money class
```

This operation is not adding 50 to the MoneyAmount, it's setting MoneyAmount to that exact value.

Did you mean to say this instead?:

```
Money.MoneyAmount += 50;
```

This is equivalent to the following:

```
Money.MoneyAmount = Money.MoneyAmount + 50;
```

(See [+= operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-assignment-operator))

Comment: Thank you a lot "doppelgreener" for your attention and reply it works perfectly now :)

Comment: @Mir Please mark it as the accepted answer.